# unable to find bundle named STKAudioKit_STK

Tags: audiokit

I am working on an app, which works without any issue with AudioKit 5.0 (v5-main branch), now with the new version (5.2.0) split in multiple modules, I have added the 3 modules as shown bellow. I get the below error when running the app :

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SwiftPMResourcesAccessor', reason: 'unable to find bundle named STKAudioKit_STK'

I am using Xcode 12.5.1

[packages and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ACc5.png)

AudioKit cookbook compiles and runs perfectly and I can use the flute recipe which seem to rely on the STK also.

Any idea how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed now but I guess this is due to a typo in the AudioKit STK :

NSString *bundleName = @"STKAudioKit_STK";

should be :

NSString *bundleName = @"STKAudioKit_Stk";

after making this change it works.